# Give Username Permission to Modify Files on AWS Instance Using chown Linux Command

Tags: linux, chown

Using PuTTY, I tried giving one of my usernames access to an instance on AWS using the following Linux command:

```
chown -R userName /var/www
```

However, I got the following error message on each folder/file:

chown: changing ownership of ‘/var/www/’: Operation not permitted

How can I give userName permission to modify /var/www? I guess first I need to give myself the power to grant ownership to another username, how would I do that?

Comment: Questions like this belong to [su]. It's [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to be root to set that permission. By default EC2 instances use the `ec2-user` user which does not have sufficient permission, but does have access to sudo.  Verify who you are by typing:

```
whoami
```

You can use sudo like this:

```
sudo chown -R userName /var/www
```

But be careful doing this. It is general good practice to have web files owned by one user and give read permission to the user presenting the web files (for example apache). But that is outside the scope of this question.